# d3.each() storing values one at a time, not all at once

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to store the x and y coordinates of some rects into an array. There are 20 rects and I'm storing the values in an array of 20 arrays. Each item in the array looks like this:

```
[
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ];
```

I added a `.each()` to my rect append like so:

```
.each(function(d,i) {
    return polyMaster[i][0].y = d3.select(this).attr('y');
 })
```

At this point I noticed that all the `y` values were the same. I confirmed this by trying:

```
.each(function(d,i) {
    return polyMaster[i][0].y = i;
})
```

Which returned `19` -- the last index. So it seems all my previous indexed `y`s are being overwritten by the new ones.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var outerRadius = (400 / 2);
var innerRadius = 15;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+ ")");

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([.01,.09])
    .range([7,50]);

var data = [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.027},
  {'manager': 'Deutsche Bank', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.025},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.033},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.066},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.084}];

  var poly = [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ];

  var polyMaster = new Array(20).fill(poly);

  var colorMap = {
    'Fidelity':"#003366",
    'BlackRock':"#366092",
    'SSgA':"#4f81b9",
    'Hang Seng':"#95b3d7",
    'UBS':"#b8cce4",
    'Schroders':"#e7eef8",
    'JP Morgan':"#a6a6a6",
    'Value Partners':"#d9d9d9",
    'Yuanta':"#ffffcc",
    'First State':"#ffffcc",
    'HSBC':'#f6d18b',
    'Invesco':'#e4a733',
    'BOCI-Prudential':"#b29866",
    'Allianz':'#a6a6a6',
    'Mirae Asset':'#d9d9d9',
    'Manulife':'#e7eef8',
    'CSOP':'#b8cce4',
    'Principal':'#95b3d7',
    'Deutsche Bank':'#4f81b9',
    'Aberdeen Standard':'#366092',
    'ChinaAMC':'#003366'
  };

      var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.share - a.share;
      });

      let counterRect = 0,
        counterText = 0;

        var column = graphGroup.selectAll('.ranks')
            .data(sortedData)
            .attr('class', 'ranks')
          .enter().append("g");

        column.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 120)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return heightScale(d.share)
            })
            .attr('x', function(d) {return 0})
            .attr('y', function(d, i) {
              let previous = counterRect;
              return (counterRect += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous)
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (i>=0) {
                return polyMaster[i][0].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (i>=0) {
                const index = i;
                polyMaster[index][0].y = d3.select(this).attr('y');
              }
            })

            .style('fill',function(d,i) {return colorMap[d.manager]});

            column.append("text")
              .attr('x', function(d) {return 60})
              .attr('y', function(d, i) {
                let previous = counterText;
                return (counterText += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous + (heightScale(d.share)/2))
              })
              .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.manager;
              });

              console.log(polyMaster)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

How do I store my rect's `y` attributes iteratively, but still one at a time (so as to avoid being overwritten)?

**Note:** I'm just worried with the first object of `x` and `y`s. The remaining three will be mapped out later, once I figure out how to do the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `d3.each` or its indices. Your problem lies here:

```
var poly = [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
];

var polyMaster = new Array(20).fill(poly);
```

All your objects in all your arrays point **to the same** object (`poly`). Changing one will change them all.

A quick fix would be using `JSON.parse` with `JSON.stringify` to copy the objects:

```
var polyMaster = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)))
```

There are several alternatives, though. Another simple one is just passing the array directly inside the `map`:

```
var polyMaster = d3.range(20).map(()=>[
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
])
```

Also, as you noticed, I'm using `d3.range` instead of `new Array` + `fill`.

Here is the changed code:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var outerRadius = (400 / 2);
var innerRadius = 15;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+ ")");

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([.01,.09])
    .range([7,50]);

var data = [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.027},
  {'manager': 'Deutsche Bank', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.025},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.033},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.066},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.084}];

  var poly = [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ];

  var polyMaster = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)))

  var colorMap = {
    'Fidelity':"#003366",
    'BlackRock':"#366092",
    'SSgA':"#4f81b9",
    'Hang Seng':"#95b3d7",
    'UBS':"#b8cce4",
    'Schroders':"#e7eef8",
    'JP Morgan':"#a6a6a6",
    'Value Partners':"#d9d9d9",
    'Yuanta':"#ffffcc",
    'First State':"#ffffcc",
    'HSBC':'#f6d18b',
    'Invesco':'#e4a733',
    'BOCI-Prudential':"#b29866",
    'Allianz':'#a6a6a6',
    'Mirae Asset':'#d9d9d9',
    'Manulife':'#e7eef8',
    'CSOP':'#b8cce4',
    'Principal':'#95b3d7',
    'Deutsche Bank':'#4f81b9',
    'Aberdeen Standard':'#366092',
    'ChinaAMC':'#003366'
  };

      var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.share - a.share;
      });

      let counterRect = 0,
        counterText = 0;

        var column = graphGroup.selectAll('.ranks')
            .data(sortedData)
            .attr('class', 'ranks')
          .enter().append("g");

        column.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 120)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return heightScale(d.share)
            })
            .attr('x', function(d) {return 0})
            .attr('y', function(d, i) {
              let previous = counterRect;
              return (counterRect += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous)
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (i>=0) {
                return polyMaster[i][0].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (i>=0) {
                const index = i;
                polyMaster[index][0].y = d3.select(this).attr('y');
              }
            })

            .style('fill',function(d,i) {return colorMap[d.manager]});

            column.append("text")
              .attr('x', function(d) {return 60})
              .attr('y', function(d, i) {
                let previous = counterText;
                return (counterText += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous + (heightScale(d.share)/2))
              })
              .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.manager;
              });

              console.log(polyMaster)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```